# Reputation: is there something helpful I can do to get it?

Tags: discussion

I am fluent in Spanish and English, Is there a way for me to earn reputation by offering a Spanish translation of useful posts?

Comment: If you link me to some of your posts, I'll do my best to offer a good Spanish translation.

Comment: Questions here are Superuser are expected to be in English only.  Questions or answers submitted in another language are subject to removal by the community per the help center.  [There are language specific versions of Superuser in the pipeline.](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/354/help-out-our-other-spanish-language-proposals).  *Your edits wouldn't be approved if you added translations to existing questions or answers anyways.*

Comment: The best thing you can do to gain reputation is to answer questions to the best of your abilities.

Comment: Because you are bilingual you have the capability of being able to find interesting posts on the web that most people who use this site can't read. Not all of the material on the web that is relevant to this website is written in English.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, good to know.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way for me to earn reputation by offering a Spanish translation of useful posts?

As summarized in comments, posts on Super User are expected to be in English only and as such posts not in English will be deleted if the OP doesn't update. Decent way to build up bit by bit of rep is to offer [suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) to posts which can be improved, other than the most obvious parts of answering whatever questions you can